# code ot check if data entry already exist

Tags: ms-access

I have a form where the user enters data "last name"

I am trying to put a code together that checks if the data entered for "last name" already exists in a database, and if it does, for a message box to appear advising the user that the last name already exists, and then giving them the option on whether they would like to continue in adding that "last name" into the database.

ive written the code several different ways, with if statements and dlookup, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Please post your current code so that we may advise of the issues and how to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out**

```
Private Sub btn_Click()

    'variable declaration
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim retVal As Variant

    'get textbox value into variable. Nz function checks for null and replaces it with empty string in case its nulll
    lastName = Nz(Me.txtLastName, "")

    'dcount function checks the count of lastname in tblUser
    If DCount("*", "tblUser", "LastName='" & lastName & "'") > 0 Then
       retVal = MsgBox("Name already exist. Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)

       If retVal = vbYes Then
        'your insert statement

       Else
        '
       End If

    End If

End Sub
```